# Python - set array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Could you tell me why my for cycle does not work? I think it should be able to solve it somehow with cycle and I missed something. It is not a hot problem, bud I would like to know where is mistake in my idea. I have tried it in python 3.7 and 3.8 which I have installed.

```
a = input("Input a: ")
b = input("Input b: ")
c = input("Input c: ")
d = input("Input d: ")

##doesn´t work (if it is an empty string, set it to 0)
for i in (a,b,c,d):
    if i == "":
        i = 0

##work perfect
##if a == "": a = 0
##if b == "": b = 0
##if c == "": c = 0
##if d == "": d = 0

array = [a,b,c,d]

print(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `for i in [a,b,c,d]:`
Instead

Comment: This did not help. It is still the same output with empty strings.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in this code:

1) 
If you want to change value to 0, you need to create a separate variable for that list i.e. lst=[a,b,c,d] before for loop.  Your statement will be : for i in lst:

2)
It is because in your for loop statement your using '( )' which is tuple operator and tuple is immutable data structure ( You cannot change value of Tuple once intialised ). 
Just change that '()' to '[ ]' list operator, since list is mutable.

```
a = input("Input a: ")
b = input("Input b: ")
c = input("Input c: ")
d = input("Input d: ")

lst=[a,b,c,d]

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[ i ]== "":
        lst[i ]= 0

print(lst)
```

OR 
use itertools.

Comment: I tried both ideas and the output is still the same. Only ["", "", "", ""]

Comment: You need to remove that array=[a, b, c, d]. Directly print the list i.e. print(lst) as per my solution.

Comment: This looks like it is working - I get list. But my idea was, that I could use array or list to check, if some variables content is an empty string. And if it is "", then set variable content to 0. But it looks like dead end and bad idea. Thank you all for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning 0 to i. Not to any of the variable a,b,c or d .
Just convert those input into list first and then if condition matches assign the list element zero, not the loop variable i.

`array = [a,b,c,d]
 for i in range(len(array)):
      if array[i]=="":
          array[i] = 0`

Comment: This looks like it is working - I get list. But my idea was, that I could use array or list to check, if some variables content is an empty string. And if it is "", then set variable content to 0. But it looks like dead end and bad idea. Thank you all for your time and attention.